# EMFILE error on bulk data insert

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm developing an loopback application to get data using oracledb npm module from ORACLE and convert it to JSON format to be stored in MONGODB.
MONGODB is accessed using **"loopback-connector-mongodb"**.

The data to be stored would be around for 100 collections as of for 100 tables from ORACLE. 
I'm pushing data with http request row by row for the entire collection list from node server from my local application to another server application on remote machine using http-request through remote method call.

When the data write operation the remote machine application stops throwing an error showing `"EMFILE error"`.

I googled and some reference showed that it is because of the maximum number of opened files/sockets. Hence i tried disconnecting the DataSource for each request. Still i'm getting the same error.

Please help me on this!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making an http request for each row of data, and aren't throttling or otherwise controlling the order of those requests, it is possible you are simply making too many requests at once because of node's async io model.

For example, making those calls in a simple for loop would actually result in all of them being made in parallel.

If this is the case, you might want to consider using something like the async module, which includes some utilities for throttling the parallelism.

Comment: Thanks @Ryan for suggesting. but i have control over the data sent and received to and from server with call back functions as per **node's async io model** (row by row looping through **recursive function** and **not for loop**). Even though i did these, i got the error.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget Oracle Database 12.1.0.2 has JSON support.  Maybe you don't need to move the data in the first place?

See [JSON in Oracle Database](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/json.htm#ADXDB6246).  To quote the manual:

> 'Oracle Database supports JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) data
>   natively with relational database features, including transactions,
>   indexing, declarative querying, and views.'